# One line Conditional constructs in python

Tags: python, coding-style, conditional-statements

In **javascript**, I could make one-line conditional constructs, like:

```
var Verbose = true; // false
if ( Verbose ) console.log("Verbose mode");
```

In shell scripting ( **bash** ), I could make one-line conditional constructs, like:

```
Verbose=false # true
[ $Verbose == true ] && echo "Verbose mode" || echo "Silent mode"
```

How can I make the same in **python**?

This is necessary for wrapping "verbose" messages in big and deep recursion methods. I can wrap it by function or use two lines, like:

```
if Verbose:
         print "Verbose mode"
```

But this is looks too ugly.

Comment: You can write it in one line `if Verbose: print "Verbose mode"`. No porblem.

Comment: If you're using 3.x or 2.6+ with a future import and would like other developers to want to kill you, you can completely abuse something like: `verbose and print('Verbose mode')` but please don't - it's purely for reference. Nothing wrong with your if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python lets you have `if` and guarded statement on a single line:

```
if verbose: print('verbose')
```

PEP 8 discourages this, as a matter of style; but Python still allows it (and will forever:-) and I personally don't mind it when the guarded statement is short and structural (such as `break`, `continue`, &c)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out you can put the if and print on a single line.
But just for completeness and an awful use of python short circuiting you can write:

```
verbose = True
verbose and print("Verbose mode")
```

But this is ugly.
You can even achieve the equivalent of your bash statement

```
verbose and not print("Verbose mode") or print("Silent mode")
```

But this is even uglier :)

Comment: `verbose and print("Verbose mode")` - looks nice. Thank you. However, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @litigious.formalism it's because you're using python2 and this answer assumes python3.  In python3 `print()` is a function

Comment: Just remove the parens for python 2. I forget as I even have my python 2 environment push `from __future__ import print_function` into the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have covered

```
if verbose: print 'Verbose'
```

but for your middle example needing an `else`, you could use a ternary

```
print 'Verbose' if verbose else 'Silent'
```

Though the stylistic merits of this are... questionable